# Mongo DB query/search in field that is a map<String, List<Integer>>

Tags: mongodb, list, dictionary, search

Im store a java Map> in mongo db field.
Now I need do search in this map to find if specific KEY in the map has some ID in their list.
Here is an exemple of stored mongo document with this sample map:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("595ce6b73167ad0d882ca384"),
    "ROLES_RULES" : {
        "2" : [ 
            1198
        ],
        "7" : [ 
            473, 
            474, 
            476, 
            1214, 
            1241, 
            1249, 
            1258, 
            1549, 
            1602
        ],
        "8" : [ 
            1477, 
            1549
        ],
        "10" : [ 
            1265, 
            1273, 
            1581
        ]
    }
}
```

Then for exemple, I need to find docs that have "ROLE_RULES" of key "7"(or another) that have values (1241,23,xxx,..) in their id list.

In other words, I need to find a doc with value or values in their list of values in an specific map key/index.

it is possible with this storaged structured ? Or I need to restrucutre this map with a class with field names or something like.

Thanks

Comment: try this: `db.collection.find({"ROLES_RULES.7": {$in: [1241,23]}})`

Comment: thanks a lot, it works fine!